# Using a for loop to create three adjacent box plots for each of the numeric variables of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, boxplot

I have been trying to create a "for loop". I wanted to loop through the various columns of the "iris" data frame, thus creating a boxplot for each numerical variable as a function of the "species" variable (which is character). The boxplots have to be together (3 adjacent to each other). I believe there is also something wrong with my use of the par() function.

Thanks!

```
mybp<-NULL
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
for (i in colnames(iris)){
  if (class(iris[,i]) == 'numeric'){
  par(mfrow = c(1,3))
  mybp<-boxplot(data=iris, iris[, i]~Species, main="variable by flower species", col=c("green","blue","red"))
  }
}
mybp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option:

```
names(which(sapply(iris, is.numeric) == TRUE)) -> x #numeric columns 
par(mfrow = c(1,length(x)))

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  
  boxplot(data=iris, iris[, x[i]] ~ Species, main="variable by flower species", col=c("green","blue","red"), ylab = x[i])
  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are four numeric columns, so you may want to use four adjacent plots to each other.

You may make this simpler than in a `for` loop. The `names(iris)[sapply(iris, is.numeric)]` gives you the column names of the numerical columns. The outer `sapply` then loops through these names and creates `boxplot`s. Using `reformulate` you get the formula for each iteration, e.g.  `Sepal.Length ~ Species` for the first one.

For a common title we use `title`.

```
op <- par(mfrow = c(1,4))

sapply(names(iris)[sapply(iris, is.numeric)], function(y) 
  boxplot(reformulate("Species", y), iris, col=2:4))
title("Variable by flower species", line=-2.5, outer=TRUE, cex.main=2, font.main=2)

par(op)
```

[image]

However, you can also fix your `for` loop. You don't need to assign anything in the loop:

```
for (i in colnames(iris)) {
  if (class(iris[,i]) == 'numeric'){
    boxplot(data=iris, iris[, i] ~ Species, main="variable by flower species",
                  col=c("green","blue","red"))
  }
}
```